# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

```
 const data = suggestedEmbed.embeds[0];
```

Hi, I'm having this error and I don't know why it is saying that the code above is the problem. Any solutions for this problem? Thank you for reading.
**Code:**

```
module.exports = {
  category: "Utility",
  description: "Accept valid suggestions!",
  expectedArgs: "<messageID> <Reason>",
  minArgs: 2,
  guildOnly: true,
  ownerOnly: true,
  callback:  ({message, args}) => {
    const messageID = args[0]
    const acceptQuery = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    try{
      const suggestionChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('834459599699443782');
      const suggestedEmbed = suggestionChannel.messages.fetch(messageID);
      console.log(suggestedEmbed)

      const data = suggestedEmbed.embeds[0];
      const acceptEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(data.author.name, data.author.iconURL())
      .setColor('GREEN')
      .setDescription(data.description)
      .addField(" Status ✅ Accepted! Expect this coming soon!", acceptQuery);

      suggestedEmbed.edit(acceptEmbed);

      const user = client.users.cache.find((u) => u.tag === data.author.name);
      user.send("Your suggestion has been accepted! Thank you for this suggestion, expect this coming soon!")
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that `suggestionChannel.messages.fetch(messageID);` is really returning the message that you are getting with the id argument?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `suggestedEmbed.embeds` is undefined, as the error suggests, then something is probably going wrong with fetching the message with `suggestionChannel.messages.fetch(messageID);`

Comment: so how do I fix this problem sir?

Comment: You could just try debugging the code by `console.log()`ing the variables down the line to see what is causing the error

Comment: `MessageManager#fetch()` returns a promise- you need to await it or use `.then()`

Comment: @Lioness100 i tried to use the await but it doesn't work bc i dont have the "async" function involved and idk how to include the async function in it also i dont know where to use the .then() however if you could tell me where to place it, it would be a pleasure.

Comment: To make an async function just change `callback:  ({message, args})` to `callback:  async ({message, args})` and replace `suggestionChannel.messages.fetch(messageID);` with `await suggestionChannel.messages.fetch(messageID);`

Comment: i got it! thank you so much @Lioness100